# SAGA 8.5.1 cmd not working on Linux RStudio Server RedHat 7.9

Tags: raster, saga

Trying to run saga_cmds on RStudio Servier but cant get `saga_gis()` to work. SAGA Version 8.5.1 cmd not working on Linux RStudio Server RedHat 7.9

```
library(Rsagacmd)

> saga <-saga_gis(raster_backend = "terra")
```

> (process:5503): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:17:19.209:
> g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE
> (instance)' failed Error: could not load any tool library Error: 'NA/'
> does not exist in current working directory
> ('/home/28002014081507527221684/DS_sagsa').